# Wordpress and PHP includes

Tags: php, html, wordpress, php-include

If I was looking to use my own HTML for a certain page on my wordpress theme, how can I go about it?

Please advise where code should go

If I can use raw HTML or PHP INCLUDES.

Comment: I would recommend providing a link to the site or an example. Also, which theme are you using?

Comment: Hi Matt, the link is Relus.com Theme: Salient

Comment: Are you trying to use this custom HTML as your main page content for a specific page? Or are you trying to insert into the header, footer, etc.?

Comment: All of the above Matt. Thanks for responding

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to place the HTML in the main page content, just use the text editor of WordPress(http://www.wpbeginner.com/glossary/text-editor/). The header & footer would be modified inside the `header.php` and `footer.php` files of your theme. the directory where these would be located should be `/wp-content/themes/salient/`. If you want the header and footer to only be modified only on specific pages, you will want to use the is_page() function built into WordPress(https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page).

Example of limiting header or footer modification to specific page:

```
<?php if( is_page( 42 ) !== false ) { ?>
    <!-- HTML that should only appear on page with id of 42. -->
<?php } ?>
```